# tcolorbox: list of tcolorbox (\tcblistof...) looks different from LaTex list of figures (\listoffigures) - How can I change it?

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, tcolorbox, scrbook

[image]How can I change the appearance of the lists of tcolorboxes (Section 5.2 of the tcolorbox manual)?

Problem:
The list of tcolorboxes using the command \tcblistof looks different compared to the list of figures provided by the standard LaTex command: \listoffigures

1. The tcolorbox list is a list without vertical space from chapter to chapter.
2. Furthermore, there is no space between the number and the caption.
3. If a provide a space between the number and the caption using the \quad command, then the numbers of the list are not aligned vertically.

I would like that all lists provided have the same appearance, that means, either change the appearance of the list of figures or change the appearance of the list of tcolorboxes.

Do you have a recommendation/solution?
Below is an example of the code that I use to produce a List of Definitions and List of Figures.

Help highly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

% Creation of dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}

%  Environments for my definitions and examples
\usepackage[listings,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=definitions]{definitionbox}[2][]{%
    colframe=red,%
    colback=white,%
    sharp corners=all,%
    boxrule=0.5pt,%
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,%
    title=Definition~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1,%
    list entry= \thetcbcounter: #2,#1}%


% A definition can be provided within the following environment:
%\begin{definitionbox}[breakable]{Title of Definition}
%\end{definitionbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=examples]{examplebox}[2][]{%
    colframe=blue,%
    colback=white,%
    sharp corners=all,%
    boxrule=0.5pt,%
    lower separated=true,%
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,%
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1,
    list entry= \thetcbcounter: \quad #2,#1}%

% An example can be provided within the following environment:
%\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example}
%\tcblower
%\end{examplebox}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Add List of Definitions to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Definitions}
% List of tcolorboxes, see documentation, Section 5.2
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{definitions}{List of Definitions}

% Add List of Examples to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Examples}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{examples}{List of Examples}

% Add List of Figures to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Important Chapter}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{definitionbox}[label={def:derivative}]{Financial Derivative}
    A financial derivative is a financial contract that is settled at a future date $ T>0 $.
\end{definitionbox}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example}
Testexample.
\tcblower
Test example solution.
\end{examplebox}


\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}
    Testtext 1  for figure environment.
    \caption{Testcaption 1}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}



\chapter{Even More Important Chapter}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{definitionbox}[label={def:spotprice}]{Spot Price}
    The \emph{spot price} $ S_0$ is the price for immediate delivery at $ t=0 $.
    The spot price $ S_t $ is the (market) price of an asset at a point in time $ t $.
    The spot price $ S_T $ is the (market) price of an asset at maturity $ T $.
\end{definitionbox}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example 2}
    Testexample 2
    \tcblower
    Test example solution 2.
\end{examplebox}


\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}
        Testtext 2  for figure environment.
        \caption{Testcaption 2}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The specific spacing may related to the document class in use, here `scrbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add the LoF manually to ToC. You should use class option `listof=totoc`.

Replace the `list entry` option for the tcolorboxes by

```latex
list text=#2
```

and add the following code

```latex
\addtotoclist[float]{definitions}% same vertical gap for chapters 
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofdefinitions}{}{\listoftoc[List of Definitions]{definitions}}
\setuptoc{definitions}{totoc}% ToC entry for the list of definitions

\addtotoclist[float]{examples}% same vertical gap for chapters
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofexamples}{}{\listoftoc[List of Examples]{examples}}
\setuptoc{examples}{totoc}% ToC entry for the list of examples
```

Then use `\listofdefinitions` and `\listofexamples` for the list of definitions and the list of examples.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrbook}% option listof=totoc added
\usepackage{scrhack}% added

\usepackage{blindtext}% Creation of dummy text

%  Environments for my definitions and examples
\usepackage[listings,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=definitions]{definitionbox}[2][]{%
  colframe=red,%
  colback=white,%
  sharp corners=all,%
  boxrule=0.5pt,%
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,%
  title=Definition~\thetcbcounter: #2,
  %#1,% <- removed
  list text=#2,% changed
  #1}%

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=examples]{examplebox}[2][]{%
  colframe=blue,%
  colback=white,%
  sharp corners=all,%
  boxrule=0.5pt,%
  lower separated=true,%
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,%
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,
  %#1,% <- removed
  list text=#2,% changed
  #1}%

% ---- added:
\addtotoclist[float]{definitions}
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofdefinitions}{}{\listoftoc[List of Definitions]{definitions}}
\setuptoc{definitions}{totoc}

\addtotoclist[float]{examples}
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofexamples}{}{\listoftoc[List of Examples]{examples}}
\setuptoc{examples}{totoc}
%---

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofdefinitions% <- changed
\listofexamples% <- changed
\listoffigures

\chapter{Important Chapter}
\blindtext
\begin{definitionbox}[label={def:derivative}]{Financial Derivative}
  A financial derivative is a financial contract that is settled at a future date $ T>0 $.
\end{definitionbox}
\blindtext
\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example}
Testexample.
\tcblower
Test example solution.
\end{examplebox}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Testtext 1  for figure environment.
  \caption{Testcaption 1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Even More Important Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{definitionbox}[label={def:spotprice}]{Spot Price}
  The \emph{spot price} $ S_0$ is the price for immediate delivery at $ t=0 $.
  The spot price $ S_t $ is the (market) price of an asset at a point in time $ t $.
  The spot price $ S_T $ is the (market) price of an asset at maturity $ T $.
\end{definitionbox}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example 2}
  Testexample 2
  \tcblower
  Test example solution 2.
\end{examplebox}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Testtext 2 for figure environment.
  \caption{Testcaption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Testtext 3 for figure environment.
  \caption{Testcaption 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example 3}
  Testexample 3
  \tcblower
  Test example solution 3.
\end{examplebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

If there should be no gap etc. for chapters in the lists use KOMA-Script option `listof=nochaptergap`:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=totoc,listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}% options listof=totoc and listof=nochaptergap added
\usepackage{scrhack}% added

\usepackage{blindtext}% Creation of dummy text

%  Environments for my definitions and examples
\usepackage[listings,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=definitions]{definitionbox}[2][]{%
  colframe=red,%
  colback=white,%
  sharp corners=all,%
  boxrule=0.5pt,%
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,%
  title=Definition~\thetcbcounter: #2,
  %#1,% <- removed
  list text= #2,% changed
  #1}%

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=examples]{examplebox}[2][]{%
  colframe=blue,%
  colback=white,%
  sharp corners=all,%
  boxrule=0.5pt,%
  lower separated=true,%
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,%
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,
  %#1,% <- removed
  list text= #2,% changed
  #1}%

% ---- added:
\addtotoclist[float]{definitions}
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofdefinitions}{}{\listoftoc[List of Definitions]{definitions}}
\setuptoc{definitions}{totoc}

\addtotoclist[float]{examples}
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofexamples}{}{\listoftoc[List of Examples]{examples}}
\setuptoc{examples}{totoc}
%---

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofdefinitions% <- changed
\listofexamples% <- changed
\listoffigures

\chapter{Important Chapter}
\blindtext
\begin{definitionbox}[label={def:derivative}]{Financial Derivative}
  A financial derivative is a financial contract that is settled at a future date $ T>0 $.
\end{definitionbox}
\blindtext
\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example}
Testexample.
\tcblower
Test example solution.
\end{examplebox}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Testtext 1  for figure environment.
  \caption{Testcaption 1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Even More Important Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{definitionbox}[label={def:spotprice}]{Spot Price}
  The \emph{spot price} $ S_0$ is the price for immediate delivery at $ t=0 $.
  The spot price $ S_t $ is the (market) price of an asset at a point in time $ t $.
  The spot price $ S_T $ is the (market) price of an asset at maturity $ T $.
\end{definitionbox}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example 2}
  Testexample 2
  \tcblower
  Test example solution 2.
\end{examplebox}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Testtext 2 for figure environment.
  \caption{Testcaption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Testtext 3 for figure environment.
  \caption{Testcaption 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{examplebox}[breakable]{Title of Example 3}
  Testexample 3
  \tcblower
  Test example solution 3.
\end{examplebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the right way to thank is. Your solution works perfectly! Thank you! Beste Grüße aus Vancouver nach Deutschland!